# Append text to file using sed

Tags: bash, shell, text, sed, edit

How can I write text to a file using sed? More specifically I would it add null variables to my blank text file that was created using touch. The syntax of sed is very confusing to me.

Comment: If the file is empty, why do you need to use `sed`? Just `echo` or `printf` what you want into the file.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, along with your results, and an example of the output you're expecting.

Comment: @Barmar `echo` and `printf` are not working in `find . -exec printf "xx" > {} \;` . and I don't want to use loop. Here `sed` works.

Comment: `>` is processed by the shell, `find` never sees that. It doesn't execute `-exec` using the shell.

Comment: Use `-exec bash -c 'printf "xx" > "$1"' {} {} \;`

Comment: @AsukaMinato What does that have to do with this question?

Comment: @Barmar oh, thanks. It didn't come to my mind that I can use `bash -c` to do that. So I thought I need to use `sed` .

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you're just appending text to the end of the file then you wouldn't use sed in the first place.

```
echo "some text" >> somefile.txt
```

Comment: I've been using an example to change variables in a file, I thought maybe you could add them too. This is MUCH simpler.

Comment: In this case you don't need `touch` at all :)

Answer (score 45):

Use `$ a`.

```
sed -i "$ a some text" somefile.txt
```

Comment: It's useful to know how to actually do this with sed. Sometimes you want to use sed to make multiple changes to a file, including adding a line to the end, and it's nice to be able to do that in a single command.

Comment: This does not work for an empty file (0 bytes) created by `touch` (like asked).

Comment: specially useful since it can be used with `sudo`, while `sudo echo > file` would be doing a `sudo echo` and then redirecting the output *as non-sudo* to `file`

Comment: This is a syntax error on MacOS and other *BSD platforms. The `a` command is not properly standardized by POSIX so whether or not it works on an empty file is probably platform-dependent. The syntactically correct `sed -i '' 'a$\ ` (newline) `some text' somefile.txt` does not actually modify an empty file on MacOS Big Sur, like @doak already remarked (presumably regarding Linux).

Comment: This adds the text on a new line, what if I want to append it inline? Do I really have to use `s/$/.../`?

Answer (score 10):

Adding a late post because while the accepted answer is the simplest solution to this problem, the question actually highlights a couple of common situations:

1. Need to edit a file via sudo
2. Trying to use `sed` to modify an empty file.

In short, you can't `touch`, then edit a file with `sed`.
Sed doesn't work on empty files, but occasionally you need to do the equivalent of

```
sudo echo "some text" >> somefile.txt
```

sudo doesn't like the redirect, but there are workarounds:

```
echo "some text" | sudo tee --append somefile.txt
```

or if pipes are not an option either, or you simply *must* use sed, or you just like complexity:

```
dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=1 of=somefile.txt
sed -i '$ a some text' somefile.txt
sed -i '1 d' somefile
```

On some systems,. you might have to use `sed -i -e '$ a ...`

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me.  You might get better or more useful answers if you ask about what problem you're trying to solve, rather than asking for help implementing a particular solution.

But if you absolutely must do this in sed, you can use sed's `r` command to read a file.  For example:

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ cat one
RED
BLUE
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ cat two
green
yellow
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ echo ">> start"; sed '$r two' one; echo ">> end"
>> start
RED
BLUE
green
yellow
>> end
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$
```

The sed command `$r two` causes sed to slurp in the file named "two" after processing the last line of input (which in this case is from the file "one").

Note that this merges one file into the stream of another file, but sed's "standard output" (`stdout`) is what contains the full/combined stream.  You can redirect that output to a file per Ignacio's answer if that's what you want.

Comment: thanks for the info. I think it's beyond the scope of what I'm doing. You can check out my script tho. http://pastebin.com/TGvmWmfG My next goal is to have it write the launch deamon from within the script instead of copying it. Show me how that could be done?