# Append file(s) to a file without redirection (">>") in Bash

Tags: bash, ansible-2.x

I have a remote file (two actually) that I wish to concat to another remote file. I want to use the command module in Ansible rather than the shell module. Therefore I can't use `>>` (or `|` or `&&` etc).

Question is twofold: is there a module (or combination) that will do this for me?

And, if not, is there a bash command which will do this for me?

I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289522/append-text-to-file-using-sed) that `sed -i "$ a some text" somefile.txt` will append a line of text.

A hypothetical command to illustrate:

```
append -in /my/remote/file -in /my/remote/file2 -out /my/remote/dst
```

Comment: `awk '{print>f}' f=out in1 in2 in3` ; `sed -n wout in1 in2 in3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed, you could use in-place editing and the [`r` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-r-_0028read-file_0029-command):

```
sed -i '$r file2' file
```

which on the last line of `file` will append (`r` for "read") the contents of `file2`.

As for an Ansible module, I don't know Ansible well at all, but [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) might work?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your requirement has all file to be merged in one folder. If so, you can use below code

```
- name: Assemble from fragments from a directory
  assemble:
   src: /my/remote/
   dest: /my/remote/dst
```

```
Initial:
# ls
file1  file2
# cat file1
this is file1
# cat file2
this is file2

After running playbook:
# cat dst
this is file1
this is file2
```

Comment: Unfortunately not all in the same folder for me, but this answer might help someone else.